# Existence result for an operator obtained by integrating Laplace-Beltrami operator to normal direction in Fermi coordinate

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-operators, existence-theorems

I am going through some literature and encountered with some known facts about Fermi coordinate and Laplace-Beltrami operator. Let $u$ be a function on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $\Gamma_0$ be a $0$ level surface of $u$, and $\Gamma_z$ be a surface with signed distance from $\Gamma_0$ is $z$. Laplace operator in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ can be written as (I would like to know the initial reference to this. Seems to be well-known fact, but couldn't find a proper source)
$$\Delta_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}=\Delta_z-H_{\Gamma_z}\partial_z+\partial_{zz},$$
where $\Delta_z$ is Laplace-Beltrami operator on $\Gamma_z$ and $H_{\Gamma_z}$ is the mean curvature of $\Gamma_z$. One may derive the formula
$$\Delta_z=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(g_{ij}(y,z))}}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\left(\sqrt{\det(g_{ij}(y,z))}g^{ij}(y,z)\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\right),$$
where $g(\cdot,z)$ is the metric tensor restricted to $\Gamma_z$.

In this context, for any $f\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, let
$$L(f):=\int_{-R}^R\Delta_zf\,dz.$$
Obviously $L$ is a linear operator.

**Question**: Is there any existence result to Dirichlet problem of this operator?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a note on terminology. I believe that it is _Gaussian normal coordinates_ that are adapted to normal geodesics with respect to a codim-1 hypersurface. _Fermi normal coordinates_ on the other hand are adapted  to normal geodesics radiating out from a 1-dimensional curve.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I've quite often seen the term Fermi coordinates used with the same meaning as in the question. Indeed I would say that it is standard in some subfields - see e.g. papers of Pacard or Chodosh-Mantoulidis; Gray's 'Tubes' defines them in this sense also. My impression is that the term is overloaded, and has different meanings in different areas. (Incidentally, Pacard's 'The role of the minimal surfaces in the study of the Allen-Cahn equation' should have a derivation of the expression for the Laplacian - I'm not sure what the initial reference should be, however.)

Comment: @LeoMoos You may be right. My comment should be interpreted within the subfield of Riemannian Geometry/General Relativity, which incidentally where Fermi's original contribution was made. I think I've also seen _(general?) Fermi coordinates_ refer to coordinates adapted to geodesics normal to a submanifold of any codimension. Still, more search hits may be found by using historically established names in special cases, Gaussian (codim 1), Riemann (dim 0), Fermi (dim 1).

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I didn't mean to contradict your comment, I just meant to make a remark on the use of the term I've encountered. You're completely correct in pointing out that the distinction you make (between Fermi and Gauss coordinates) seems to be quite common, particularly in GR; at least that's what an online search for the terms indicates. I'm grateful that you pointed this out in your comment, as I hadn't been aware of the differing nomenclature!